# Which is bigger - the Star Forge, or the Death Star?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, a-new-hope, death-star, return-of-the-jedi

If you've played *Star Wars:  Knights of the Old Republic*, you're familiar with the Star Forge:

I haven't found any definitive information regarding the size of the Star Forge, but I know that the **conservative estimates for the sizes of the Death Stars are 120 km diameter and 160 km diameter respectively.**

Estimates for the Star Forge itself vary DRAMATICALLY:

> Star Forge Diameter = 91 kilometers
>
> Star Forge Height = 272 kilometers
>   -  [Source](http://www.narutoforums.com/blog.php?b=19661)

And:

> Star Forge Diameter = 11 kilometers
>
> Star Forge Height = 28 kilometers
>   -  [Source](http://calypso1577.blogspot.com/2013/11/size-of-rakatan-starforge.html)

I think SF&F can do better than this.

### Assuming that these estimates of the Death Stars' sizes are correct, which is bigger?  The Star Forge, or the Death Star?

Comment: Turns out that this was debated [on forums back in 2004](http://forums.obsidian.net/topic/7937-whats-bigger-star-forge-or-death-star/) and an objective answer was never reached. Although I liked the poster who said that it was the Death Star because it was on a cinema screen instead of a computer screen.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Any way you slice it, the Death Star is much larger.

Based on the information given in the question concerning the specs of the Death Star, its radius is no smaller than **60,000 m**, which gives a volume of **9.05 x 10<sup>14</sup> m<sup>3</sup>**.

Now, here is the Star Forge:

[image]

Based on this information about Hammerheads supplied by the OP,

[image]

(in particular that the length of the Hammerhead is **315 m**), and based on this video also supplied by the OP,

I used some frames when the Hammerheads are between the fins of the Star Forge to give an upper bound on the diameter of the spherical part of the Star Forge as being at most **20 Hammerheads**, which works out to a maximum radius of **3150 m**.  This gives a volume of **1.31 x 10<sup>11</sup> m<sup>3</sup>** for the spherical part.

Now, there are six fins on the Star Forge, three on top and three on the bottom.  Now, let's say that each fin has twice the volume of the sphere, which is a gross overestimate given how thin they are.  That would make the total estimated volume of the Star Forge thirteen times the volume of the central sphere, which is roughly **1.7 x 10<sup>12</sup> m<sup>3</sup>**.

This still makes the Death Star a whopping **530 times more voluminous** than the Star Forge (9.05 x 10<sup>14</sup> divided by 1.7 x 10<sup>12</sup>).

Even if I make the radius 20 Hammerheads (instead of a diameter of 20 Hammerheads) — which is another gross overestimate on the Star Forge — I still get that the Death Star is bigger, but only by about **65 times**.

**Another Way to Compare:** If we suppose that the Star Forge were a sphere, with radius from the center to the end of the longest fin, that would be about 60 Hammerheads — but let's say 80 to overestimate.  This gives a radius of **25,200 m**, which is still less than half the radius of the Death Star (and makes the Death Star about **15 times** the volume of this sphere), and the actual volume of the Star Forge would be much less than that of this pretend sphere.

Answer (score 5):

**This answer addresses the first revision of the question before later edits were made.**

There has never been an official source that states how big the Star Forge is. The best I could find is [a fan estimate](http://calypso1577.blogspot.com/2013/11/size-of-rakatan-starforge.html):

> First image tells us that the station is 72.5 times wider than its control tower.
>
> Second image tells us that the tower's width is roughly half of a Hammerhead's length. A Hammerhead is apparently 315 meters long, according to Wookieepedia, so the tower is roughly 155 meters wide.
>
> That leaves us with a total width for the Star Forge of slightly over 11 km and an height of around 28 kilometers, give or take a kilometer in either direction. Actual figures might be slightly higher, but for ballpark figures these are pretty good.

Given that the first Death Star has a 120 km diameter and the second a 160 km, the Death Stars have a diameter about 11x and 14.5x larger respectively than the Star Forge. Also given that the Star Forge is not a sphere, the Death Star has a great deal more volume.

Comment: All comments moved to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34791/discussion-on-answer-by-thunderforge-which-is-bigger-the-star-forge-or-the-de)

Answer (score 2):

There is a second way to do this which instead puts the star forge at a similar size to Saturn (116,460km diameter). In the [picture on Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Forge?file=StarForgeSucksGas-KOTOR1.jpg), we see it drawing matter from a star while  perfectly side on, this gives us a direct comparison between it and the star it orbits, using [an online compass tool](https://www.mathspad.co.uk/i2/construct.php) to complete the circle the result I got was this:
[image: Single Star Forge compared to diameter of sun]

If I then simply line up equally sized Star Forge pictures along the star until I get to the centre point we see that it is around 1/12 the diameter of the star it orbits and since this star supports life and I am lazy, I will therefore assume it is a star similar to our sun which has a diameter of 1.3927 million km, the resulting width would therefore be 1,392,700/12=116,058.3 km, obviously this answer could scale somewhat depending on the star, it appears to be a yellow dwarf or G type main sequence star which gives a possible radius of between 0.85 and 1.1 times the radius of the sun or multiplying those numbers by the original answer a possible range of 98649 to 127664 km, while there is likely a significant margin of error it is clear that when doing the calculation in this way the result is guaranteed to be vastly larger than either death star, even if we use the smallest star possible, a red dwarf with a radius of 0.102 R (R being the radius of the sun) we have 696350 times 0.102 which is 71027.7 times 2 for the diameter and then divided by 12 for the width of the star forge gets a width of 11837.95 km and if we then assume a margin of error of even 20% it is still 9470.36 km in width which is approximately 47 times that of the second death star (given a diameter of 200km by wookiepedia) before we even take the fins into account.

[image: Four Star forges compared to Death Star diameter]

Comment: Welcome to the Science Fiction and Fantasy StackExchange! Do you have any details further details that you could either link or add into your answer? (such as the diameter of saturn, or the online tool that you used to come to your final calculation?)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's not clear to me that the star is in the same plane as the Star Forge; if it's in the distance the relative sizes could be much different.

Comment: @DavidW It is obviously in the same plane, as the star forge is drawing matter from the star.

Comment: I applaud the work you've done, but I don't think we can expect a videogame or even Star Wars to represent accurately the curvature of a star's "surface" in relation an object in its proximity. I think it's just a fictional depiction, like explosions and lasers going pew pew in space.

Comment: oh yeah of course, star wars has always been ridiculous that way and this number is clearly too big, I just did this since it is a different way to calculate the size rather than the more common hammerhead corvette comparison.

Answer (score -1):

Following New Hope, proportional blueprints of ISD and DS1 appeared . But ISD was described just 500meters in length; further investigations concluded 1600 meters in diameter; it lead to diameter length of DS1 was 222km ( with radius 111 km); with canonized ratio 16/12 , it lead to 300 km diameter of DS2; it isn't bad proportion: with Endor's diameter 4900km maximum for DS2 was 420km, but with another comparation with ISD shadow ,270+ km /345 +-100km/ described as really diameter; 300km for DS2 is correct dimension.
Star forge may have 90km diameter of central sphere.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you provide any references for this?  And some more concrete numbers for the size of the Star Forge?

Answer (score -2):

We can found many arguments about DS2 diameter: it wasn't 900km because Endor hadn't Earth or Venus sized diameter. Endor has 4900km in diameter.
About Star Forge that is not easy. Centerpoint station has length approximately equal with Death Star 2 ; A comparation Centerpoint vs Star Forge will be interesting.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Some sources for this would help a lot; where do you get that Centerpoint is the same size as the Death Star 2?

Comment: In fact centerpoint is longer : it had 350km in main axis ; exist another calculation about DS1 and DS2: DS1 with 162km diameter and DS2 with 216 km diameter; 120 km was prototype Geonosis DS.