# How does the size of the Death Star compare to the Yorktown Station in Star Trek Beyond?

Tags: star-wars, star-trek, death-star, star-trek-beyond

As the question states, how does the size of the Death Star compare with the Yorktown space station featured in *Star Trek Beyond*?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a gorilla vs shark question

Comment: I'm asking about the relative size of both stations as while there is a lot of information about the size of the death star there is little information about the size of the Yorktown base

Comment: @ATB Although the two objects appear in different universes, it's possible that this question is objectively answerable. If the sizes of both objects are known according to some common measuring system (e.g. metres or tonnes), then it's not gorilla vs shark. See also [this post about the policy on GvS questions](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/06/gorilla-vs-shark-not-so-fast/).

Comment: I'm voting to leave open for the reasons pointed out by @Rand

Comment: @mooz - The question is **objectively answerable** since the OP is asking about the measurements and since those measurements can be confirmed out-of-universe.

Comment: Wow, Yorktown Station looks like a big toy in a hamster ball. Nothing like Spacedock Earth in the pre-retcon movies: http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Spacedock_(Earth).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is a graphical depiction of how the two objects would look side-by-side, based on the best *canonical* evidence we have about their sizes.

[image]

---

According the the concept artist for Star Trek Beyond, [Sean Hargreaves](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sean_Hargreaves), the outer diameter of  Yorktown Station is **40 miles**.

> **Q.** *Do you remember how big Yorktown is supposed to be.*
>
> **Sean Hargreaves:** *About 40 miles in diameter at the outer glass sphere.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Facebook: Sean Hargreaves Design](https://www.facebook.com/sean.hargreaves.design/posts/10207300144845349)</sup></sub>

By comparison, the canonical size of the Death Star (the first one) is **75 miles in diameter**. The Second Death Star is **99 miles in diameter**.

[image]
<sub><sup>[Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Absolutely_Everything_You_Need_to_Know)</sup></sub>

Comment: Are all the light sources on the Death Star windows? Just how big would those windows have to be to be visible on a station that size?

Comment: @JAB - I honestly don't know. Looking over the images from the Death Star Assault, you can't actually see any windows (or even any light sources); http://i.stack.imgur.com/MWfsw.png

Comment: Considering the size of the thing, and the quantity of bright spots on the equator, they're more likely to be landing bays or other massive doors than windows... Unless they're deck-spanning panoramic windows, anyway.

Comment: @JAB: City lights on Earth are visible from space if sufficiently clustered.

Comment: Love seeing them side by side but such a pity that they are lit from opposite sides.

Comment: @CandiedOrange - Your merest whim is my dearest desire.

Comment: I've changed this for the accepted answer because it makes more sense for the whole diameter of the yorktown station to be bigger than it's arms as confirmed by the sources you included

Comment: @Valorum Wonderful! Now make me a sandwich ;)

Comment: @CandiedOrange - It's waiting on the table for you; http://static.messynessychic.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/foolsgold.jpg

Comment: Uh Rich.. *cough* I mean @Valorum, that table seems dusty... also, is that peanut butter, jelly and ham???

Comment: @Ryan - That's the class "Elvis" style golden Peanut butter, Jelly and bacon sandwich. 7000 calories per serving if made correctly.

Comment: @Valorum, 7k? I used to swim 10-12k meters a day, which would let me eat... one of these. And that's it. For the whole day. And only on the 12k days otherwise I'd still be 500 hundred over what I burned for the day. Your saying Elvis ate these? No wonder he got fat...

Comment: @Ryan - According to his biography, his eating these is something of a myth. He once flew to Denver to get one after he was told that they were good. History doesn't record if he ever ate another one.

Answer (score 28):

According to [Sean Hargreaves](http://www.thetrekcollective.com/2016/08/the-art-of-starbase-yorktown-from-sean.html), the designer of the Yorktown, each arm is intended to be 17.5 miles long and they open into the interior ball. This means the radius of the station is a little bit more than 17.5 miles or 28.16 km.

The death star, is said to have a diameter of 87 miles (DS1), or 99 miles(DS2).  Both are significantly bigger than the Yorktown.

In fact, if you want to compare it in size to another Star Wars battlestation/large object, it's a bit bigger than the star forge, [which has a radius of 25 km](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116040/which-is-bigger-the-star-forge-or-the-death-star)

Comment: upvote for the imperial-metric conversion!

Comment: Alas, you've failed to take into account that there are two arms extending from the outer hub, plus a gap between the arms and the outer wall.

Comment: @Valorum I was going off of known value and making a rough estimate based off of that.  The gap and the ball inside combined are significantly less than one of the arms. That's why I said a 'little bit more' where a little bit is a approximately 2.5 miles more.

Comment: I've sourced the quote for the 17.5 Miles figure which seems to be from an article on TheTrekCollective.com

Comment: @JesusGomez heh, Imperial conversion ...

Comment: You may wish to also note that your figure of 87 miles comes from the (non-canon) Star Wars Enclyclopedia

Comment: @CBredlow Please compare radius to radius, or diameter to diameter: it's a bit hard to follow, atm.